# Drawing app for android that has Wacom support

Tags: android, drawing

I'm looking for a drawing app for Android tablets that has Wacom Pen and Touch tablet support. I have tried using [Bamboo Paper](http://www.wacom.com/en/us/everyday/bamboo-paper) but it only has support for phones, or at least not the Asus TF300T tablet.

Some features I am looking for:

- Support for wacom drawing tablets
- Must work with Android tablets (like the Asus TF300T)
- Changing pen colour
- Different brush types (pen, thick brush, pencil etc)
- Shapes (circle, square, and line)
- Save to .PNG format
- If possible an easy clear button, but not required

Comment: I have a bamboo and I remember reading a post that says Android used to support bamboo via OTG before 4.1, you can try downgrading your tablet hence all apps will work with the bamboo